# Execute a Google AI Platform Notebook from Command Line

Tags: google-cloud-shell, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have a Google AI Platform Notebook, that i would like to run from some kind of command line tool.

The end goal, is to schedule this AI Notebook such that it runs at a specified time every day or week. Fully scripted.

I think I need to first open up a VM instance and then run the Notebook AI on that instance. I know that GCP have a lot of cloud products that should facilitate the above (scheduler, pub/sub, compute, function), but i'm not ready to "marry" Google at this point.

Br, Torben

Answer (score 3):

You can use papermill [link](https://github.com/nteract/papermill).

> papermill is a tool for parameterizing, executing, and analyzing
>   Jupyter Notebooks.

Then you can write a write a `script.sh` on your VM (Linux):

```
papermill local/input.ipynb gs://bkt/output.ipynb -p alpha 0.6 -p l1_ratio 0.1
```

Create a cronjob to run your your script.sh, for example every day at 10:10 AM:

```
contab -e
10 10 * * * /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: What if I have a notebook ai instance and I want from my local computer to run a specific notebook on that instance on the cloud?